# What is the default parameter for AUTOLOAD in Perl?

Tags: perl, oop, autoload

I've been playing with `AUTOLOAD` to create my accessors in Perl and I have encountered this confusion (I have searched google and perldoc already).

I have this code:

```
package Class;
sub new {
..code for constructor here.
}

sub AUTOLOAD {
 my $name= shift;
 print $name;
}
```

But when I do something like : `my $a=Class->new;` The autoload subroutine still executes, and prints `Class=HASH(some weird number)`;

I thought AUTOLOAD only runs when there is an undefined method or subroutine?

And also I did this:

```
my $class = our $AUTOLOAD;

print $class #prints ::DESTROY
```

Am I right when I assumed that `DESTROY` is the value of $AUTOLOAD when no undefined function is passed?

Comment: Please forget about AUTOLOAD! It may have its uses sometimes, but creating accessors is not one of them.

Comment: I've spent 6 hours figuring this out and im about to understand it completely if that confusion above gets cleared, so no!

Comment: OK, so go figure it out and then forget about it. You won't regret it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using Autoload is inherently difficult. If you want a solid object system that makes accessors for you then **please use Moose, Mouse, Moo**, or just loop over your fields and install the accessors yourself:

```
BEGIN {
  my @fields = qw/foo bar baz/;
  for my $field (@fields) {
    no strict 'refs';
    # install a closure in the package stash.
    *{ __PACKAGE__ . "::" . $field } = sub {
      my $self = shift;
      $self->{$field} = shift if @_;
      return $self->{$field};
    };
  }
}
```

---

If a class that can `AUTOLOAD` encounters an undefined method, the `AUTOLOAD` sub is called with the arguments of the missing sub. The fully qualified name of the requested sub is passed in the `$AUTOLOAD` package variable.

A typical Autoload sub would look like:

```
use Carp;

my %fields_allowed = map {$_ => 1} qw/foo bar baz/;

sub AUTOLOAD {
  my $field = our $AUTOLOAD;
  $field =~ s/.*:://; # strip the package name
  $fields_allowed{$field}
    or croak qq(Can't locate object method $field via package "@{[__PACKAGE__]}");
  my $self = shift;
  $self->{$field} = shift if @_;
  return $self->{$field};
}
```

There remain two problems:

- When the reference count of an object drops to zero, or when a thread terminates, the `DESTROY` method is called on the object if it provides one. We can prevent autoloading of `DESTROY` by providing an empty implementation: `sub DESTROY {}`.
- We can ask any object if it can perform a certain method, like `say "Good dog" if $dog->can("roll")`. Therefore, we have to override `can` to support our autoloading. The `can` method is useful for safe duck typing. Every object inherits from `UNIVERSAL`, which provides default implementations for `can` and `isa`.

The contract of `can` is that it takes the name of a method. It will return `undef` when the object cannot perform the method, or a code reference to that method if it can. A suitable implementation would be

```
sub can {
  my ($self, $name) = @_;

  # check if it's a field of ours
  if ($fields_allowed{$name}) {
    return sub {
      my $self = shift;
      $self->{$name} = shift if @_;
      return $self->{$name};
    };
  }

  # Ask SUPER implementation of can if we can do $name
  if (my $meth = $self->SUPER::can($name)) {
    return $meth;
  }
  return; # no method found
}
```

We can now simplify `AUTOLOAD` to

```
sub AUTOLOAD {
  my $field = our $AUTOLOAD;
  $field =~ s/.*:://; # strip the package name
  my $code = $self->can($field)
    or croak qq(Can't locate object method $field via package "@{[__PACKAGE__]}");
  goto &$code; # tail call; invisible via `caller()`.
}
```

---

This is a lot of complexity to get right. Verdict: Don't use Autoload because you think it might be less work. It never is. It is quite useful for implementing a proxy pattern, but that is a bit advanced.

I urge you to dabble around with OO basics, and the Moose object system, before diving deep into Perl's unique and strange features.

Comment: yeah about that trimming the package name, I forgot to do that so it added another field in my constructor `Packagename::method`. So what I did is put `use fields (specify what I want)`. But it still add that field? why is that?

Comment: The `use fields` is *ancient* technology, and provides compile time checking of hash keys and a constructor (`new`). Don't use it without good reason. Rather, stick to vanilla Perl OO and write a hash-based `new` yourself, or use a modern object system like `Moose`.

Comment: I see your point there in your first batch of code. Question: this one: `*{ __PACKAGE__ . "::" . $field }` It's a typleglob to my package right? How do I access the newly created method then?

Comment: And another question, what is the name of that `__blahblah__` (underscored thingy) so that I can perldoc that one?

Comment: The `__PACKAGE__` holds the name of the current package. We create the fully qualified name of the sub we want to create, and then use that string as a symbolic reference (therefore `no strict 'refs'`). We dereference it to a type glob, and assign it a code reference. As this happens in a `BEGIN` block (during compile time), this is similar to a normal sub declaration. Some underscore tokens like `__PACKAGE__` behave like normal subroutines and are documened in `perlfunc`. Command line: `perldoc -f __PACKAGE__`. See also [perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Special-Literals).